# \pagestyle{plain} between chapters without page number after titlepage?

Tags: titles, conditionals, blank-page

I've found numerous posts about removing the header/footer on the blank pages between chapters, and they work fine with one big exception... I need a `\pagestyle{plain}` (i.e. single centered pg#) at all blank pages before chapter starts in the document **except** I need a `\pagestyle{empty}` for the page *right after* the `\titlepage`. All the methods I've seen and tried either leave me with completely empty pages for the whole document or `\pagestyle{plain}` for all of them.

I'm using `book` document class `[twosided,openright]`, `fancyhdr`, and have included the code to redefine `\cleardoublepage` as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\def
\cleardoublepage{%
\clearpage
  \ifodd\c@page
  \else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \newpage      
  \fi
  }%
\makeatother
```

...as recommended in various posts. Unfortunately, that leaves me with the blank page after the `titlepage` with a page number (which is driving the client nuts). The code seems to override any inline attempts to get that page to `{empty}`.

Is there some form of `\if@titlepage` conditional that parallels `\if@mainmatter` I could use to clear just that section and leave the rest (`\frontmatter, \mainmatter, \appendix, \backmatter`) as `\pagestyle{plain}` for those in-between blank pages? Is there some way to capture that as a conditional?

A (very) rough approximation MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,final,openright]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}

\pagestyle{fancy}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

  \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
      \if@mainmatter
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}
      \else
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
      \fi
      }%
  \makeatother  

  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small \thepage}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\small \leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\small \rightmark}

% Redefine \pagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\small \thepage} % except the center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }%

% Code for creating plain on empty pages before new chapter
\makeatletter
\def
  \cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage
      \ifodd\c@page
      \else
        \hbox{}
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        \newpage      
      \fi
    }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% TITLE PAGE
\pagestyle{empty}  %Clear hdr/ftr 
\titlepage
  \input{./Chapter_txt/titlepageV1} %Custom title page text/layout

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{fancy} % Resume hdr/ftr
%MANAGEMENT SUMMARY 
\include{Preface} %Intro/Preface chapter

%ToC and Lists  
\tableofcontents
\listoftables   
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\part{PartI}
  \include{Chapter1}
  \include{Chapter2}
\part{PartII}
  \include{Chapter3}
  \include{Chapter4}

\appendix
  \include{app}

\backmatter  
    \bibliographystyle{humannat}
    \bibliography{mybib}\footnotesize
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

The whole thing is a multi-volume work, with each section drawn in by `\include{file}`... not a good way to do much of an MWE (don't know how to do one that has `\input` or `\include`).

Comment: you need : 1) titlepage -->2) empty--> 3 + plain like this?

Comment: @touhami, almost... for "3+" I need `fancy` for the main body and `plain` for those situations where there's a blank even-page after parts/chapters.

Comment: There is a difference between `\thispagestyle` and `\pagestyle` commands. The former defines the page style for the current page only, while the latter defines for the entire document.

However, there is not much we can do to help you without a MWE example. Can you provide one?

MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @CarlosViegas, I'll try and put up an MWE soon. I do understand the difference between `\thispagestyle` and `\pagestyle`, but according to the examples I've found `\thispagestyle` is appropriate in this case since it's just redefining the even-page instance of a `\cleardoublepage` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution **Edit: more explanation**

pagestyle is fancy, pages between chapters are set to `plain` by redefining `\cleardoublepage` (this last command is used by `\part` and `\chapter`)

the page after part page is set to `plain` by redefining `\@endpart`

the page after title page is set to `empty` by this pagestyle{empty} just after `titlepage` environment

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}  
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} 
\fancyfoot[R]{test} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\mtcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\mtcleardoublepage}}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{plain}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\makeatother
\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-20]
\part{Deux}
\chapter{trois}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

**Edit: code for this particular**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}

\pagestyle{fancy}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}

  \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
      \if@mainmatter
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}
      \else
        \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
      \fi
      }%
  \makeatother  

  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small \thepage}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\small \leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\small \rightmark}

% Redefine \pagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\small \thepage} % except the center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }%

\let\mtcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\mtcleardoublepage}}
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
               \if@openright
                \null
                \thispagestyle{plain}%
                \newpage
               \fi
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
test
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter

\include{Preface} %Intro/Preface chapter

%ToC and Lists  
\tableofcontents
\listoftables   
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\part{PartI}
  \include{Chapter1}
  \include{Chapter2}
\part{PartII}
  \include{Chapter3}
  \include{Chapter4}

\appendix
  \include{app}

\backmatter 
\footnotesize 
    \bibliographystyle{humannat}
    \bibliography{mybib}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a place I can find a list of those conditionals (`@endpart, @tempswa`, etc), or a way to know which environments have some such macro?

Comment: here for example https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base file: classes.pdf

Comment: Tried it... I still end up with the `plain` style page for the blank page after the titlepage...

Comment: in this example there is no blank page after title page

Comment: if i understand may be you shoud use `\thispagestyle{empty}\frontmatter`

Comment: @Scard i edit my answer i add your code.

Comment: This code got exactly the result I was looking for, but I admit that I don't quite understand how it achieves it. Why does this allow the `\thispagestyle{empty}` after the title page work where the other ones kept getting overwritten by the `{plain}` style?

Comment: @Scard a add some explanation

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to redefine your `titlepage` environment.
Mine is like this, and the first page after titlepage is empty and the following are numbered correctly.

```
\newenvironment{titlepage}
{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
}%
{\newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
}%%
```

Moreover, if you use `\maketitle` command, you should add a `\clearpage` at the end of the command definition:

```
\if@titlepage
\newcommand\maketitle{%
  \begin{titlepage}
...
  \end{titlepage}%
  \clearpage%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
...
}%
\fi
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `\newenvironment` over-writes the existing `titlepage` definition for the `book` class? Definitely worth a try. The project is actually in 4 separate `.tex` main documents sharing a custom `.sty`... that would simplify if I can drop it in there.

Comment: You can redefine the `book` class directly (the `sty` file) or create a new environment at your `.tex` and overwriting the default one.

Comment: Get the error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \titlepage already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... }`...

Comment: @Scard -- you probably want `\renewcommand{\titlepage}{...}`.

Comment: @Scard my code is to replace the corresponding code in the `sty`. Otherwise you need to redefine it.

Comment: Ah... okay. Misunderstood. I'll give that a try in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the package [`scrextend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) with the option `cleardoublepage=plain`. To get an empty page right after the titlepage use `\cleardoubleoddemptypage` after the `titlepage` environment or as last command inside this environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge My Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoubleoddemptypage
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is the additional use of [`etoolbox`:](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)

```
\documentclass{book}
%
\usepackage[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrextend}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{titlepage}{\cleardoubleoddemptypage}
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge My Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\blinddocument
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```