# Removing fancy style from part pages

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr, parts

I am using the fancyhdr package to set headers and footers for the thesis. I have recently added LaTeX `\parts`, and defined a pagestyle for this purpose called 'partpagestyle'. As the MWE below shows, the 'onlycount' style correctly removes the header on the first page of every chapter. I have defined 'partpagestyle' to clear the formatting of `fancyhdr`, but it does not have the desired result. I have perused the manual (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Clear everything on part pages
\fancypagestyle{partpagestyle}
{
\fancyhf{}
}
% First page of chapter style
\fancypagestyle{onlycount}
{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\sl{\bf{\leftmark}}}}}
\rhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\sl{\bf{\rightmark}}}}}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}%
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\huge \bfseries Thesis
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Introduction}\thispagestyle{onlycount}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[1-3]

\part{Some Part}
%\thispagestyle{partpagestyle}
%\thispagestyle{partpagestyle}

\chapter{Second Chapter}\thispagestyle{onlycount}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: try to replace plain by fancy in your code

Comment: Do you mean to say replacing `\pagestyle{plain}` by `\pagestyle{fancy}` etc? My code does not compile with this change.

Comment: Please do not use `\bf` etc. Those commands are outdated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\part` macro from `report.cls` always has a `\thispagestyle{plain}` in its setup, so redefining the `plain` style with a header rule of thickness `0.1mm` will show such one.

`\fancyhf{}` does only clear the individual fields of the header and footers, but **not** the header or footer rules. To clear this, I added `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` to the `partpagestyle` definition.

This code patches the `\part` command to use `partpagestyle` instead of `plain`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Clear everything on part pages
\fancypagestyle{partpagestyle}
{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
% First page of chapter style
\fancypagestyle{onlycount}
{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\textsl{\bfseries{\leftmark}}}}}
  \rhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\textsl{\bfseries{\rightmark}}}}}
  \chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% Patch the `\thispagestyle` code within `\part    
\xpatchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{partpagestyle}}{}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\huge \bfseries Thesis
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Introduction}\thispagestyle{onlycount}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[1-3]

\part{Some Part}


\thispagestyle{onlycount}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can also patch `chapter` command

Comment: @touhami: Yes, I considered it, but you know the proverb: Leave it as an exercise ;-)

Answer (score 2):

this is a way

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\textsl{\bfseries{\leftmark}}}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\textsl{\bfseries{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\huge \bfseries Thesis
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[1-3]

\part{Some Part}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, even shorter than mine ;-) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i just answer question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240238/pagestyleplain-between-chapters-without-page-number-after-titlepage/240244#240244 usuelly i don't use xpatch but i learn from you

Comment: `xpatch` and `xparse` are Swiss knives ;-)